# Querying .DBF with PHP

Tags: php, odbc, dbf

I was given a dbf table and asked to write a PHP page to display the data in the table. I am working on this project with XAMPP. I have followed this guide: http://www.yinfor.com/2008/01/php_connect_dbf_file.html in setting up the odbc and placed my dbf file in the same folder as the php file (in xampp directory, under test folder).

Here's my test codes:

```
<?php

    require_once('odbc.php');
    $strsql= 'SELECT * FROM test/apvend.dbf';
    $query = odbc_exec($odbc, $strsql) or die (odbc_errormsg());

    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo 'Client Name: '.$row['NAME'];
    }

    odbc_close($odbc);
?>
```

This is the error message:

```
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\test1.php on line 5
[Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause.
```

Can anyone help? I am relatively new coder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's written there:

```
Syntax error in FROM clause
```

Try to change your code as follows:

```
$strsql= 'SELECT * FROM "C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\apvend.dbf"';
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I changed the code and now the error is:

"
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]SourceDB, SQL state 01S00 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\odbc.php on line 2
Could Not Connect to ODBC Database!"

Comment: Oh never mind I got it working already. Turned out that I did not configure my data source properly.

Here's a better guide for people who work with ODBC first time: http://cicorp.com/data/odbc/